# autocompletion based on 'contains' rather than 'begins with'?

Tags: spyder

I was wondering if autocomplete in Spyder editor(python) can show results on containing a part of a keyword rather than begins with part of a keyword, like now is the case. So if I type 'child'; the suggestion list also shows 'winfo_children'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, that's not possible at the moment (December 2022), sorry.